# How can I rotate image/sprite with touch on spriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, rotation, touch, sprite-kit, image-rotation

I am trying to make a sprite rotate with one finger touch. Honestly, i have no idea how to do it, new to spriteKit.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want it to keep on rotating as long as you touch? or for a set duration? or a set amount?

Comment: Do you want to the rotate the sprite to a specific angle based on the location of the user's touch or simply spin the sprite indefinitely?

Comment: thanks people (:this guy down there solved it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would rotate the sprite to where you touch using an action. If you'd want it to rotate while dragging the finger. You should remove the action and do the calculation on the `touchesMoved:` instead.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

    sprite.xScale = 0.5;
    sprite.yScale = 0.5;
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height/2);

    [self addChild:sprite];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];


        float dY = sprite.position.y - location.y;
        float dX = sprite.position.x - location.x;
        float angle = atan2f(dY, dX) + 1.571f;
        [sprite runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:0.5 shortestUnitArc:YES]];
        return;
    }
}
```

Alternatively: (Remember to remove the code from the `touchesBegan:`

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        float dY = sprite.position.y - location.y;
        float dX = sprite.position.x - location.x;
        float angle = (atan2f(dY, dX)) + 1.571f;
        sprite.zRotation = angle;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, i want it to rotate it while dragging the finger. But what do you mean by removing the action, how will the sprite rotate without an action? A code might be helpful... Thanks again!

Comment: The touchesMoved: method gets called every time the touch moves, which is quite a lot of times. If you added an action every time it would probably look weird and be quite inefficient. So you must update rotation manually. I updated the answer the alternative solution.